# Reduce 'X' hours from a column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table 'ABC' with a column TIME_THU which has values like 04:00, 04:02,04:03. The column is VARCHAR2 and I need to reduce the column value to 00:00, 00:02,00:03 i.e. reduce them by 04 hours back.

Need to use UPDATE query to make changes to this.

Something like,

```
Update ABC set TIME_THU  = TIME_THU -4;
```

Thanks

Comment: What about values less than 04:00?

Comment: Luckily the data is under our control and includes scheduled time when we need a job to be fired. Rather than creating new rows, we wanted to reuse the same ones by adding/subtracting hours. The below works for me.             Update ABC set TIME_THU = to_char(to_date(TIME_THU,'hh24:mi')-(4/24),'hh24:mi')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your data, the best option seems to be to convert to a date, subtract the hours, then convert back.

```
Update ABC set TIME_THU = to_char(to_date(TIME_THU,'hh24:mi')-(4/24),'hh24:mi')
```

The caveat here is that if any of your time are less than 4:00, you may get incorrect results. I don't know enough of you requirements to know what the correct result would be in that scenario, so I can't solve it.

---

You may also want to investigate the `interval` data type, which is better suited to storing times disconnected from a date.

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks!